# Fix missing data value while joining dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to join two dataframe one is data for choropleth with postcode and some other value in it another one is postcode and price.

I am trying to join both of them according to  correspond postcode in map_df.

After I joined them, the prices are gone and all become NaN. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Screenshots of data and/or code are discouraged here.

Comment: Mostly there are no prices for the records where `NaN` shows up, i.e. there are some postcodes available in `map_df` but not in `df`. Have you checked that? also you should use `merge` not `join`

Answer (score 0):

You should check [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) documentation. I assume you want to do a [inner join](https://soffr.miximages.com/sql/iJUMl.png) on *post_code*.

```
map_df.merge(df,how="inner",on=["post_code"])
```

Comment: This wouldn't do before renaming the merge column to `post_code` in both of `map_df` and `df`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the type of data in my map_df dataframe. I changed the postcode column from "object" to "int64".